# How do I build a HashMap in one class and then use it in another in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap

Basically all I want to do is create a HashMap object in one class, build it in that class using a loop, and then be able to call it into another class. I'm not sure what I need to do to accomplish this. I tried declaring it in the class itself and then building it in the main() function, but that doesn't allow me to access it outside of the class because it would need to be static.

Here is some psuedocode of what my thought process is:

```
public class Class1 {
    public Map<> map = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //build hashmap here using map.put etc
    }

public class Class2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //get the map using Class1.map
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code here

Comment: I think Basil's answer is the right approach... why (in the world) don't you want to create an instance of your other class? Well, if you declare everything `static` you _could_ do it, like `public static Map<> map = ...` because then Class2 could reference `Class1.map.get(...)` but then you're **not** doing object-oriented programming, you're just abusing an O-O language; you might as well learn `C` programming instead.

Comment: if I declare everything static wouldn't that disable me from inserting elements into the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I ended up just building and returning the hashmap in one method in Class1, then creating an instance of Class1 in Class2 and calling the method to return the hashmap

This was a rather simple solution, not sure why it was so difficult to find the answer. Thanks to everyone who tried to help

Answer (score 2):

## Pass object reference in method call

The `HashMap` is an object. So pass a reference to it in a method call of an object of the other class.

Make your map.

```
Map map = new HashMap() ; 
map.put( … ) ;
```

Make your other object. Here we imagine a class named `Other` that you wrote.

```
Other other = new Other() ;
```

Pass your map.

```
other.workOnMap( map ) ;
```

You can see this in action in the [*Oracle Java Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html).

## Example

Here is a complete example using four classes you might write yourself, `MapDemo.java` and `ReportTool.java` and `LoggingTool.java` and `EmployeePagingTool.java`.

In the `public static void main` method, we create an instance of our app to get going. This solves the [chicken-or-the-egg paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg) of [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). Don't focus on this method as you are learning Java. I think of it more as a hack, a crutch to get us from earth (host computer, operating system, files, memory not yet allocated) to heaven (a wonderful OOP paradise of nothing but clean objects floating around and passing messages to each other).

The real action is in the `doIt` method where we build a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) of `DayOfWeek` enum objects leading to a `String` containing the name of an employee covering some responsibility that day (such as carrying on-call pager).

An `enum` means a set of named objects already instantiated for us. In this case we have seven `DayOfWeek` objects already created for us, one for each day of the week. Nothing too mysterious here, an enum object is just an object but an object where `new DayOfWeek` was already called for you ahead of time, when the class was loaded by the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine).

We populate our map with each day of the week as the key, and each `DayOfWeek` key object leads to somebody’s name. We have exactly one name assigned to each day of the week.

Lastly, we hand off this map to another object for analysis to generate a report that gets sent to the boss. That other tool we instantiate from the class `ReportTool` (not shown here as its source code is irrelevant to this demo). Ditto for `LoggingTool` & `EmployeePagingTool`.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapDemo {

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        MapDemo app = new MapDemo();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt ( ) {
        int initialCapacity = DayOfWeek.values().length;
        Map < DayOfWeek, String > weekCoverage = new HashMap <>( initialCapacity );

        weekCoverage.put( DayOfWeek.MONDAY , "Stuart" );
        weekCoverage.put( DayOfWeek.TUESDAY , "Wendy" );
        weekCoverage.put( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY , "Lisa" );
        weekCoverage.put( DayOfWeek.THURSDAY , "Jesse" );
        weekCoverage.put( DayOfWeek.FRIDAY , "Marvin" );
        weekCoverage.put( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , "Janet" );
        weekCoverage.put( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY , "Jarrod" );

        System.out.println( weekCoverage );

        ReportTool reportTool = new ReportTool();
        reportTool.makeHtmlSummaryOfWeekCoverageAndEmailToBoss( weekCoverage );

        LoggingTool loggingTool = new LoggingTool();
        loggingTool.logWeekCoverage( weekCoverage );

        EmployeePagingTool employeePagingTool = new EmployeePagingTool();
        employeePagingTool.sendTextMessagesForWeekCoverage( weekCoverage );

    }
}
```

In real work, we would not likely be using mere `String` objects for the employee names. We would probably have an `Employee` class, and objects of that class would be assigned. In such a case we would declare our `Map` as `Map < DayOfWeek, Employee > weekCoverage`.

You may want to prevent changes to the map. One way to do that is use of `Map.of` & [`Map.ofEntries`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#ofEntries(java.util.Map.Entry...)) in Java 9 and later. Another way is [`Collections.umodifiableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap(java.util.Map)).

---

A note on [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science))… Notice how we instantiate an object from the concrete class of `HashMap`, but we store a reference to that object as the more general `Map`. We are then free to later use some other implementation of `Map` from `HashMap` to some other kind of map without in our `MapDemo` without breaking our code in `ReportTool`.

Indeed we *should* change that `MapDemo` code. While that code above compiles and runs well enough, there happens to be a better implementation of the `Map` interface when using enum objects as the key. The [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) class uses less memory and executes faster than `HashMap` when using enums as keys. Both `EnumMap` and `HashMap` implement the same `Map` interface.

So we could months later spot this opportunity to tweak our `MapDemo` code, without fearing any harm in the `ReportTool`. One of the major benefits to OOP is avoiding the age-old programming problem where one little change in one place causes other parts to blow-up.

We change these two lines:

```
        int initialCapacity = DayOfWeek.values().length;
        Map < DayOfWeek, String > weekCoverage = new HashMap <>( initialCapacity );
```

…to this single line:

```
        Map < DayOfWeek, String > weekCoverage = new EnumMap( DayOfWeek.class );
```

None of the other code need change.

Comment: I don't want to create an instance of `Other`. I want to be able to use `map` in `Other`.

Comment: @User I cannot follow the intent of your comment. This kind of question is more clear if you invent some simplistic little example. Perhaps you can restate using the `weekCoverage` example I posted here. If not fitting your issue, edit your Question to show your own invented example. But please spare us the gnarly details of your actual work.

Comment: All I want to do is build a dictionary in one class that can be used by multiple classes, so that I don't have to build it multiple times. Let's say for example I had the weekCoverage map. Then the ReportTool class would need to use the data in weekCoverage to do it's own thing.

In my code, I want to use the the data in a pre-built map to implement a simple java swing UI that obtains data from that map

Comment: @User That is precisely what I am showing. The `ReportTool` object is free to do whatever it wants with the data in our map. Perhaps it only sends the boss information for the weekend. In our `MapDemo` code here, we do not know what `ReportTool` is going to do with our map, nor do we care. The `ReportTool` class is even free to change the contents of our map. In real work, if we cared to make further use of our map here in `MapDemo`, we would actually pass a *copy* of the map in case the `ReportTool` changed the contents of our map.

Comment: @User I added more code to my example to emphasize the point that we are sharing our map with multiple other objects of various classes: a `PrintStream` object ([`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out)), a `ReportTool` object, a `LoggingTool` object, and a `EmployeePagingTool` object.

Comment: My goal is to implement several Java UIs that use the data in the map. I don't want them all running in one class.